# How do I keep track of time in a python program?

Tags: python, tkinter, time

I am writing a game using Python and Tkinter and I need to display how much time the player has left.
I need a function to run regularly and update my `time_left` variable.
I can't use a `while loop` because my program will be stuck in it forever.
How do I keep track of time here?

Comment: Could you share your code so we could understand what to do?

Answer (score 0):

To create a game i think you will still need a loop (game loop). Inside that loop, use `datetime` and `timedelta`

```
from datetime import datetime and timedelta
```

In your game loop, set a condition;

```
now = datetime.now()
if datetime.now() <= now + timedelta(minutes=How_many_minutes_you_want_to_run_the_game):
    run_the_game
else:
    stop_the_game
```

Inside that loop you can simply create a variable to store the current time OR final time(`datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=How_many_minutes_you_want_to_run_the_game) - datetime.now()`) which is time remaining.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()
while datetime.now() < (now + timedelta(seconds=2)):
    print(datetime.now())
```

This code will print the present time for 2 seconds. You can also set some delay(delay of 1 sec) to print time after each second passes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
start = time.time()
end = time.time()
time_consumed=end-start
time_left=10-time_consumed
```

10 being the time limit.
You can use this code to start noting and print the time taken by user

Comment: why are there semicolons in your python code?